# Subprogram contracts in Ada

Tags: ada, preconditions, post-conditions

I'm reading a document on Ada programming to be more specific, Ada for C++ Java developer, or I'm in trouble and to understand and be able to use some of the examples given in the document, one of them is on pre- and postconditions

But, when I compile that program, I just got a +Inf**** message - I was expecting compilation to fail because I am trying to pass 0 as the divisor.

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure main is
   
   function Divisao(Left, Right : Float) return Float
   with Pre => Right /= 0.0,
     Post => Divisao'Result * Right < left + 0.0001
     and then Divisao'Result * Right > Left - 0.0001 
   is
   begin
      return Left/Right;
   end Divisao;

begin
   Put_Line(Float'Image(Divisao(10.3,0.0)));
end main;
```

Comment: I don’t understand your PS. GNAT does have a preprocessor (*gnatprep*), but it has to be invoked explicitly; it’s not part of *gnatmake*’s processing.

Comment: http://www.adacore.com/uploads_gems/Ada_for_the_C++_or_Java_Developer-cc.pdf ... Look at page 27

Comment: "Preprocessor" is the wrong word here.  It has nothing to handling preconditions (the `Pre` aspect).  Rather, it refers to a tool that is run *before* the compiler, that takes some source code with some stuff that isn't really part of the language, and does some transformation on it to produce more "standard" source code, which is then given to the compiler.

Comment: this is one of those gotcha's that everyone getting in to SPARK probably encounters. Hopefully future searchers of 'gnat / gprbuild not failing on precondition / postcondition' will quickly find that they need to add `-gnata`

Answer (score 4):

By [ARM 11.4.2 (1.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-11-4-2.html#p1.1), pre- and postconditions are assertions. GNAT doesn’t enable assertions by default: you need to enable them by compiling with `-gnata`.

If you are using gprbuild, you will need to add something like this to your project.gpr file:

```
package Compiler is
  for Default_Switches ("Ada") use
    ("-gnata"); -- enable assertions
end Compiler;
```